# R Update | Version mismatch

Tags: r, rstudio

It's the first time I update R so I'm not too sure how it all works. I have updated R (for Windows) from RGUI and from RStudio with the installr package and updated all the packages.

In both cases I got confirmation messages that R has been upgraded to version 4.1.3:

[image: Current Version]

The new directory has been created and everything seems to be as it should.

[image]

However, when I open the projects and apps I'm working on in RStudio, I still get the old version:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "1.2"

$year
[1] "2021"

$month
[1] "11"

$day
[1] "01"

$`svn rev`
[1] "81115"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"

$nickname
[1] "Bird Hippie"
```

How do I use the new R version in my existing files?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: in RStudio, go to Tools-->Global Options, and click on "General" tab and then select the R version you want RStudio to use

Comment: In RStudio, go to Tools ... Global Options ... General ... Basic .. R Sessions. It allows you to choose a specific version of R but the default should be to use the system default version of R. Did maybe you change that at some point?

Comment: Thanks both!  I did not change the version before, but I was able to choose the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RStudio, go to Tools ... Global Options ... General ... Basic .. R Sessions.

It allows you to choose a specific version of R