# After updating R the code is not displayed anymore

Tags: r, windows, updates, missing-data

So, I updated R using the *installr* package in the Rgui. Now I face two problems:

1. My previously written code is not displayed anymore - the file is not empty, I checked it by opening the file with the editor. Opening the file by regular double clicking (RStudio is default application) as well as open the file within Rstudio by using File -> Open File -> Filename did not help. It does open the file but shows it as an empty file (no code is displayed).
2. When loading packages, I get the request for updating my RStudio. But when I use the taskbar (Help -> check for Updates) it says, that the RStudio uses the newest version.

After updating I also restarted my computer, which did no help. I also checked if the newest version is actual in use as suggested in the following post [Mismatch Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486784/r-update-version-mismatch).

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to display the code again? Thanks!

**Update**: The problem was solved by installing the newest RStudio version directly from their website.

Comment: Can't you just copy paste from the editor into a new .R file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @jay.sf This would work but does not solve the problem itself. Since **all** of my .R files are affected, I am searching for a smoother solution.

Comment: Note that `sessionInfo()` returns the R version but not that of RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I got the message wrt updating RStudio when loading packages. I will edit my question above for more clarification, in case someone else faces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found the solution - the true root of the problem was in fact an **old version of RStudio**. Besides in RStudio it was declared as the newest version, [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-graphics-engine-version-15-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio/141359) it was mentioned that these statements are not always correct.

Downloading the newest version directly from the RStudio website solved the problem.